# playing video in Samsung smart tv app

Tags: javascript, video, samsung-smart-tv

I am creating a samsung smart tv application which can play videos from a list. Right now i am working on [this](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00055/index.html#creating-the-basic-application) example provided on samsungdforum. The examples runs fine on smart tv emulator 2013 But when i click on play button , it does not plays the video.

These messages appear in debugger

```
 [JS ALERT]:  success vale :  true
 [JS ALERT]:  success vale :  true
 [JS ALERT]:  Volume : 40
 [JS ALERT]:  Volume : 40
 [JS ALERT]:  URL = 'http:&#47;/10.88.73.33/Video/Argentina.mp4'
 [JS ALERT]:  Key pressed: 71
 [JS ALERT]:  PLAY
 [JS ALERT]:  Play
 [JS ALERT]:  returnig state =1
 [JS ALERT]:  play btn clicked 
 [JS ALERT]:  URL = http:&#47;/10.88.73.33/Video/Argentina.mp4
 [JS ALERT]:  Play
```

The "Argentina.mp4" video is in my videos folder.

What am I doing wrong ? is the URl or any other thing? Please guide me towards right direction.

Thanks

Comment: i had a 2010 samsung tv which i tried to dev on. it didn't have all the codecs needed, maybe you should try a different video

Comment: @y_nk I am tryng it on 2013 samsung emulator. mp4 is supported on it.

Comment: maybe the html entity in the url (&#47;) shouldnt be escaped ? Also maybe you should monitor that the TV can get this video... It could be a simple 404 error

Comment: Does the same code (with video) works fine using a browser? Can you watch the same video using a browser (say.. Chrome)?

Comment: @Harsh . I downloaded same example and put it on my webserver with full path to xml defined on server.js but the list of videos doesnt show up on the firefox browser! could you tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. the URL normally should be of the following format http:// - take a look at your videosList.xml and clean it up
2. try this url in a browser - it does not work!

What you need to do is modify your videosList.xml to code an ABSOLUTE path to the video files - they are most likely included in your project